# Dynamic pivot in SQL server with sorted columns

Tags: sql-server, database, pivot, dynamic-programming

I wrote a script to create a dynamic pivot in SQL server, which is essentially how much each customer is paying each month.The issue is that the pivot orders the months seemingly randomly, I assume by where it finds each month? Not sure.

Anyways - I want it to create this pivot with the months in order from oldest to newest. How can I do this? The code for the dynamic pivot is below

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX) DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME([Month])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Month] FROM [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data]) AS [Month]
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT [Customer ID], ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data]
    PIVOT(SUM([Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data].[Subscription Amount]) 
          FOR [Month] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery`
```

Comment: Sample data would help, because it's unclear (to me, at least) what you mean when you say "oldest to newest". Does this mean January -> December, or are your months numbered, or is there some other meaning here? In any case, the ordering would be done when you `SELECT @ColumnName = ...` with an `ORDER BY ...` clause.

Comment: I couldn't order by because of the subquery, but I used SELECT DISTINCT TOP 99.99 PERCENT with ORDER BY and it worked